# regex.test() keep returning false when test with string from FileSystem.readAsStringAsync

Tags: javascript, regex, react-native

I'm trying to use regex to test the string. The string is read from a text file. When I test the string directly read from the text file, the regex.test() keep returning false. But when I copy the content of the text file and save it in the variable manually, the regex.test() is returning true.

This is the code that I copy the content and save it the variable manually and test() return true:

```
const verifyFileContentStructure = () => {
    const regex = new RegExp(
      /(,file_[\d]*,,)\n(x data,y data)\n((-?[\d]*.[\d]*,-?[\d]*.[\d]*,?)\n)*(,,)?/g
    );
    const fileContent = `,file_05,,
x data,y data
-970.0,-34.12164,
-959.0,-32.37526,
-949.0,-30.360199,
-938.0,-28.74816,
-929.0,-27.53912,
-920.0,-25.92707,
-911.0,-24.31503,
-900.0,-23.64334,
-891.0,-22.29997,`;
    console.log(regex.test(fileContent));
  };
```

The test() return false, when i test the text directly from the file:

```
const getFileFromLocal = async () => {
    try {
      const data = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync();
      const result = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(data.uri);
      verifyFileContentStructure(result);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
  const verifyFileContentStructure = (fileContent) => {
    const regex = new RegExp(
      /(,file_[\d]*,,)\n(x data,y data)\n((-?[\d]*.[\d]*,-?[\d]*.[\d]*,?)\n)*(,,)?/g
    );
    console.log(regex.test(fileContent));
  };
```

This is the [link](https://ufile.io/40mmt470) to download the file that I use to test the regex

I don't understand why does this problem occur, is it because the way the string is save different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often text file’s line break character is not `\n` but `\r\n` so you should use `\r?\n` in your regex